# Vim: reopen all previous files in a new session after restart

Tags: vim

I usually have long lived vim session with dozens of files open. Once in a while, I need to restart vim, say to install a new plugin or apply some new config.

How can I reopen all the previous files after restart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [builtin sessions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.4), perhaps with [vim-session plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session).

A Vim session contains all the information about what you are editing.

This includes things such as the file list, window layout, global variables,
options and other information.  (Exactly what is remembered is controlled by
the '[sessionoptions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27sessionoptions%27)' option.)

The command

```
:mksession mysession.vim
```

saves the current session into the named file. Next time you start vim you can load the session:

```
vim -S mysession.vim
```

or inside vim

```
:source mysession.vim
```

You can automate saving sessions on VimLeave autocommand and reload a session on VimEnter but be careful abut restoring a session when vim is called, e.g., from git.

Comment: In the spirit of variety, https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession is also very viable alternative to vim-session.

Comment: Also, you can add something like this to your shell's rc file to autoload sessions when there are no arguments passed when invoking from the command line (like in Boris’ answer):
`vim()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    vim -O $@
  elif [ -f "Session.vim" ]; then
    vim -S Session.vim
  else
    vim
  fi
}`

Comment: er, I'm a n00b when it comes to commenting on SO... line breaks are not respected in comments... the more ya know.

Comment: @AndrewHaust O, tpope! That's a sign of quality! Tnx! PS. 5 years at SO and you haven't noticed that comments are so primitive! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a basic setup of automatic session save / load extracted from my config:

```
let s:session_loaded = 1

augroup autosession
  " load last session on start
  " Note: without 'nested' filetypes are not restored.
  autocmd VimEnter * nested call s:session_vim_enter()
  autocmd VimLeavePre * call s:session_vim_leave()
augroup END

function! s:session_vim_enter()
    if bufnr('$') == 1 && bufname('%') == '' && !&mod && getline(1, '$') == ['']
        execute 'silent source ~/.vim/lastsession.vim'
    else
      let s:session_loaded = 0
    endif
endfunction

function! s:session_vim_leave()
  if s:session_loaded == 1
    let sessionoptions = &sessionoptions
    try
        set sessionoptions-=options
        set sessionoptions+=tabpages
        execute 'mksession! ~/.vim/lastsession.vim'
    finally
        let &sessionoptions = sessionoptions
    endtry
  endif
endfunction
```

It will only restore the session if you run `vim` without arguments, so if you do `vim somefile.txt` to do the quick edit, it will not touch the last session.

Bonus (this will restore cursor position inside files too):

```
" When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
" Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event
" handler.
autocmd MyAutoCmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 |
    \   if line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \     exe("norm '\"") |
    \   else |
    \     exe "norm $" |
    \   endif|
    \ endif
```