# how to set vim buffer like normal IdE does autosave keeping all recent opened files?without plugin

Tags: vim, buffer

I tried
:set autowrite

but I want to autosave vim buffer also like when I code last time  what size  of which file I kept and wannt to open vim buffers all same as last time.

Comment: I think you want sessions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336219/7976758

Comment: What do you want, exactly?