# How to auto-save and load temporary buffers when exiting/restarting Vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using Notepad++ for a while now for note taking and really like the feature that you can have 20 tabs open without having to save the files and they are persisted automatically. So when you need to take some notes you just open a new tab, write the notes, and close the app. Later when you open it up it will be there, saved and loaded from a temp file automatically.

Is there a way to somehow emulate the same behaviour in Vim with a plugin or setting?

I've perused through the options but haven't seen anything specific about this use case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336219/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim: reopen all previous files in a new session after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334694/vim-reopen-all-previous-files-in-a-new-session-after-restart)

Comment: Thx for the suggestions! Experimenting now with sessions, sort of what I'd need, but still have to change my usual daily workflow. What I found in the meantime is the https://github.com/abdalrahman-ali/vim-remembers plugin, that seems to do the trick for now but let me collect some xp.